# calculate range and mode on a column of numeric data

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to calculate the range and mode on a column of numeric data, lets say on COL8. It reads the CSV file in to ArrayList. I have the method getRange and method mode. I'm not sure how to proceed from here to get the desired output my code seems to be all wrong for this.

```
DATE        COL2  COL3   COL4    COL5   COL6    COL7    COL8    COL9    COL10        COL11

01-March-15 ABS    00C   Q45    Y54     49986   17724   67710   82637   22759   105396
05-April-15 ABS    00D   Q45    Y54    121953   37358   159311  217698  55205   272903
10-May-15   ABS    00D   Q45    Y54    121953   37358   159311  217698  55205   272903
22-Jul-15   ABS    00D   Q45    Y54    121953   37358   159311  217698  55205   272903

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {
        String readLine;
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));

        while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Raw CSV data: " + readLine);
            System.out.println("Converted ArrayList data: " + CSVtoArrayList(readLine) + "\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    } finally {
        try {
            if (bufferedReader != null) bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

 public static ArrayList<String> CSVtoArrayList(String splitCSV) {
    ArrayList<String> Result = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (splitCSV != null) {
        String[] splitData = splitCSV.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
            if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
               Result.add(splitData[i].trim());
            }
        }
    }

    return Result;
}

public double getRange(double[] numberList) {
    double initMin = numberList[0];
    double initMax = numberList[0];
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberList.length; i++) {
        if (numberList[i] < initMin) initMin = numberList[i];
        if (numberList[i] > initMax) initMax = numberList[i];
    }
    return initMax - initMin;
}

public static List<Integer> mode(final int[] numbers) {
    final List<Integer> modes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int max = -1;

    for (final int n : numbers) {
        int count = 0;

        if (countMap.containsKey(n)) {
            count = countMap.get(n) + 1;
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }

        countMap.put(n, count);

        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    }

    for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> tuple : countMap.entrySet()) {
        if (tuple.getValue() == max) {
            modes.add(tuple.getKey());
        }
    }

    return modes;
}}
```